# Image optimize for Flutter apps using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, flutter, mobile

I'm a bit confused about how images work for a mobile application like good size and dimensions for a good performance.

I'm ready so many articles and no one gives me a good answer, so I'm here to ask for experienced developers to give me a path to follow.

I have an application like a marketplace for clothes, so my app has lot of images and products, the problem is the images that I make a small resize from the Angular application the change the size of the image before upload.

My clients upload images like 3mb, 2mb, 4mb and I know this is not good, because of that I making resizing but my client upload a large dimension image and this is breaking my app.

Like an image that has 4500px per 2500px and only 200kbytes, this image breaks my app, so I want to know the rules of image for app maintain a good performance.

I will make a loop that will resize and optimize all the images from the app using my backend Laravel.

So in my flutter app I using this for optimization

```
 CachedNetworkImage(
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
  placeholder: (context, url) =>
      Skeleton(
    height: 200,
    width: 200,
  ),
  imageUrl:
      "${MainConfig.storageDoc + widget.companyProductList[index]['srcimglist'][0]['file_path']}",
),
```

I see some other projects that use something like Wordpress way

[image]

That makes so many image dimensions to improve performance, this is the right approach for the Mobile World?

Answer (score 0):

From what i have read, i discovered that the image mustn't exceed 2400x1600px, and should be jpeg cause it's one of most compressed techniques, for uploading you can make sure that your app only accepts that type of files with following criteria.

Also in flutter you maybe don't wanna render all the images at the same page, you maybe can divide it into pages, so you don't load all of it at the same time.
here is a link of how can you do it: https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/rendering/best-practices#render-grids-and-lists-lazily